# Perfect Separation on linear model

Tags: python-3.x, statsmodels, glm

There are lots of posts here about the `"Perfect Separation Error"` in statsmodels when running a logisitc regression. But I'm not doing logistic regression. I'm doing GLM with frequency weights and gaussian distribution. So basically OLS.

All of my independent variables are categorical with lots of categories. So high dimensional binary coded feature set.

But I'm very frequently getting the "perfectseperationerror" from statsmodels

I'm running many many models. I think I'm getting this error when my data is too thin for that many variables. However, With freq weights, in theory, I actually have many more features then the dataframe holds because the observations should be multiplied by the freq.

Any guidance on how to proceed?

```
reg = sm.GLM(dep, Indies, freq_weights = freq)


<p>Error: class 'statsmodels.tools.sm_exceptions.PerfectSeparationError'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The check is on perfect prediction and is used independently of the family.

Currently, there is now workaround when using `irls`. Using scipy optimizers, e.g. `method="bfgs"`, avoids the perfect prediction/separation check.

https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/2680

Perfect separation is only defined for the binary case, i.e. family binomial in GLM, and could be extended to other discrete models.

However, there can be other problems with inference if the residual variance is zero, i.e. we have a perfect fit.
Here is an issue with perfect prediction in OLS
https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/1459

Comment: Any of the supported scipy optimizers should work and avoid irls. It might be necessary to use `max_start_irls=0` to avoid using irls for finding good starting values for the nonlinear optimization with scipy optimizers.

Comment: Yes that's correct. I still got seperation error with only method set to scipy, but once I also changed max_start to something else it worked.

Comment: For my paticular use case this seems like an easy bug to fix. Because I'm using freq_weights statsmodels should use freq_weights in it's process for deciding whether or not to throw this error. When my freq_weights are considered i actually have far far more observations than I have features.